# Prove congruence $x^2 ≡ −a^2(\bmod p)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ be an odd prime and $a$ be any integer which is not congruent to $0 \bmod p$.

I need to prove that the congruence $x^2 ≡ −a^2(\bmod p)$ has solutions iff $p ≡ 1 (\bmod 4)$.

Comment: Reduce to the case $a = 1$.

Comment: Yes I noticed that before

Comment: So, what can you say about an $x$ such that $x^2\equiv -1 \pmod{p}$? Think of $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\ast$.

Comment: @DanielFischer It does have solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Since $a$ is not zero you can divide/cancel by $a$ to get that this is equivalent to asking if $x^2 = - 1$ has a solution $\mod p$.

It now depends a bit what you know, but here is a way.

The multiplicative group of non-zero classes modulo $p$ is cyclic;
that is there is some class $e$ such that $e,e^2, \dots, e^{p-1}$ is the set of all non-zero classes. Such an element is called a primitive root modulo $p$; another key-word in this context is "discrete logarithm."

Then $e^k$ is a square of some other element if and only if $k$ is even; the "roots" being $\pm e^{k/2}$. Now, you know that the class of $-1$ is $e^{(p-1)/2}$ and so this is a square if and only if $(p-1)/2$ is even, that is $p-1$ is divisible by $4$.

Comment: Can you provide a more elementary solution.

Comment: Sorry, no. If I can think of one I will return. I could provide more details though.

Comment: Yes can you please provide more details

Comment: $$x\sim y \iff \bigl( x = y \lor x = -y \lor x = y^{-1} \lor x = -y^{-1}\bigr)$$

Comment: @DanielFischer I havent yet learned that