# $x^2 ≡ -a^2 (\mod p)$ if and only if $ p ≡ 1 (\mod 4)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I need help proving the following:

Let p be an odd prime and a be any integer which is not congruent to 0 modulo p. Prove that the congruence $x^2 ≡ -a^2 (\mod p)$ has solutions if and only if $p ≡ 1 (\mod 4)$.

I am not really sure where to start.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is closely related to a famous result due to Fermat, and I suspect you can prove it using that theorem, but I haven't taken the time to think it through.  Here is the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares) on Fermat's theorem.  (There are many proofs of that theorem, and it is hard to say which one is easier or harder based on your background.)  Your statement of the theorem is slightly different, since (1) $a$ is given and (2) the resulting sum of two squares, $x^2 + a^2$, can be a multiple of $p$ instead of being equal to $p$.

Comment: Do you know that the equation $\;x^2=-1\pmod p\;$ has a solution $\;\iff p=1\pmod4\;$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio, yes I do, but how can I extend that for all values of a?

Comment: In addition to lacking context this question is also [a duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1149060/11619), and therefore should not be answered here at all. Mind you, that linked question isn't any better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, since you know what I asked in the comments, then

$$x^2=-a^2\pmod p\stackrel{\text{divide in both sides by}\;a}\iff \left(\frac xa\right)^2=-1\pmod p$$

and now complete the argument. (In the above,  we certainly assume $\;a\neq0\pmod p\;$, as given... ptherwise it is trivial)

Comment: I am still not really getting the connection between the x^2=−1(mod p) and this

Comment: Replace $x$ with $x/a$ and what do you get...

Comment: Did you search the site at all? Or did you somehow think this is the first time this question is asked?

Answer (score 1):

If you know about the Legendre symbol, here is a simple proof :

Notice that
$$ \bigg( \frac{-a^2}{p} \bigg) = \bigg( \frac{-1}{p} \bigg) \bigg( \frac{a^2}{p} \bigg) = \bigg( \frac{-1}{p} \bigg) \cdot 1$$
(since $a^2$ is always a quadratic residue) and that in fact the latter is equal to $1$ if and only if 
$$\bigg( \frac{-1}{p} \bigg) = 1$$
and this happens if and only if $p\equiv 1 \pmod{4}$.

So, the congruence $x^2 \equiv -a^2 \pmod{p}$ has a solution if and only if $p\equiv 1 \pmod{4}$. $\blacksquare$

Comment: How does (-a^2/p) = (-1/p)(a^2/p)? Wouldn't  (-1/p)(a^2/p) = (-a^2/p^2)?

Comment: Those are no fractions. Read the article https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol